# I need help about pass a child as a father in a method [Java]

Tags: java, inheritance, parameters

I need help about passing a Child in a method that expects a father, I have the class Person as superclass, Student and Teacher are subclasses of that class, so here is a code about what I'm trying :/

```
public static void orderByName(ArrayList<Person> pArray){
    Collections.sort(pArray, new Comparator<Person>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Student> estudiantes = new ArrayList<Student>();

    familiares.add(new Student("1235", "Name2", "SecondName2", "LastParameter2"));
    familiares.add(new Student("1234", "Name1", "SecondName1", "LastParameter1"));

    orderByName(estudiantes); //Pass an ArrayList of child but expects an ArrayList of father
}
```

I need this method also with an ArrayList of Teachers, so, is posible to pass a subtype when it expects the supertype ? Thanks I hope you can help me ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your signature with

```
public static void orderByName(ArrayList<? extends Person> pArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

A "Student" **ISA** "Person", so you can pass a Student when a Person is expected.

A "Person" is not necessarily a "Student", so you can't pass a Person when a Student is expected.

Normally we talk about subclasses, parent classes, base classes etc, perhaps read up a bit more about the correct terminology.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am something new with Java, when I call "orderByName(estudiantes);", I get an error, It says "The method orderByName(ArrayList<Person>) in the type Principal is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Student>)" :(

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, it's possible to pass the subtype when it expects the supertype.

A *Teacher* is also a person - I suppose your class definition is something like this:

```
public class Teacher extends Person {
```

So a Teacher **is** also a person and as your method expects an array list of people (Person), you can pass an array list of *Teacher*.

You will also need to use **? extends Person** in the generic - do not worry too much about it now as you are brand new to Java. Try to understand the idea of subtype/supertype and polymorphism first. After you have a good understanding of both, then you should have a close look at generics.

Just a tip: you should not expect a concrete type of ArrayList

```
public static void orderByName(ArrayList<? extends Person> pArray){ // Dont do that
```

Instead use its supertype:

```
public static void orderByName(List<? extends Person> pArray){
```

Also change where the list is assigned to the variable:

```
 List<Student> estudiantes = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Do not change anywhere else :)

The difference here is that now you can pass any subtype of list of any subtype of person.

Comment: When I use "ArrayList<? extends Person> pArray" works like I want, but if I change to 'List', I get an error and Eclipse suggest me to change to only "List pArray" and get the first error :(

Comment: His advice was actually good. When you declare a collection or that kind of things, or when you pass it as an argumennt, it is better to use an abstract type (most often an interface). Change ArrayList to List both in your declaration and in your parameters list and it will work. Let the instantiation part as it is.

Comment: @nanokuro you should change only the method and where you create the object (*List<Student>* estudiantes = new ArrayList<Student>());) You cannot change anywhere else. Sorry if I misled you. I have updated my response.